# Online c/c++ compiler for local network

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I want to compile my C/C++ programs on a remote server. The compiler is at one PC (server) and other client PC connected to the server through LAN/WLAN. The clients write program and send it to server. The server compiles the program and send the output/error to the client PC. How could I do this? How and where to start this project?

Comment: [Start by googling it.](http://ideone.com/)

Comment: Lookup "continuous integration"

Comment: Take a look at "Jenkins". There is no need for "client" to "send" code to the "server"

Comment: Please ignore prev. incomplete comment. Depends on what do you want. For automated builds take a look at "Jenkins". In this case, there is no need for "client" to "send" code to the "server". The server and client use the same VCS. When you want to make distributed builds you may find http://code.google.com/p/distcc/ usefull. Once I've seen a programming-competition website, where one could post a code by Web-interface, select a compiler and start the build. That would be a different use-case. So please specify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins sometimes is really slow and has a lot of memory leaks. If your server is a slow machine then I recommend you use Buildbot or write your own script which will be triggered after new commit into the repository. There is python.git.

http://trac.buildbot.net/

https://gitorious.org/git-python

with ubuntu it is just:

```
sudo apt-get install gitpython
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [DistCC](http://code.google.com/p/distcc), a distributed C/C++-compiler.

Comment: One issue with distcc: it works better with local preprocessing, which causes issues when you have discrepancies between the compiler version invoked on the local and remote machines. It does help, but it's not too trivial.

Answer (score 0):

One very popular solution last time is Jenkins. 
http://jenkins-ci.org/.

Jenkins can be triggered by your repository(like SVN, GIT etc). Like a watchdog - do something when you find out that there is new commit in the repository.  In example, when you are commiting into GIT repository then it will automatically run a script on the server.

That script can return a value. IF it will return(in example) false then your build is broken and red ball will be on the jenkins HTTP website and user will receive e-mail. This is how it looks:

http://www.findbestopensource.com/AppImages/Article/jenkins-img1.jpg

Jenkins can have nods. There is console output in the menu, blame, diff and a lot of free plugins. Installation is very easy even for person not connected with IT.

So only point you need to connect jenkins with your local machines is repository which for sure you are using right now;)